# Adding the effects of a RippleDrawable and a StateListDrawable to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, rippledrawable

I'm working on an app that uses a dual-pane layout on larger devices similar to what's detailed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments). A summary of the layout; one pane contains a list of options while the other will display detailed information on an option selected from the other pane.

Right now when an option is selected there is the ripple effect that's seen when selecting other elements (buttons, check boxes, etc) but after the animation completes the element returns to it's previous color. I'd like to retain the highlight from the ripple after the animation completes and I'm having trouble figuring out how to accomplish this.

This is how my ripple background currently looks. The `focus` selector doesn't do anything - couldn't figure out how to actually give the elements focus. I've also tried using a `selected` selector but that happens immediately, overriding the ripple.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorAccent">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@color/accent" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

To re-iterate, my question is this: *Is it possible to have both a ripple effect followed by a highlighted selection, and if so how?*

Comment: a hacky solution (that i tried and works) is to set your item background to a `selector` with a default item of your ripple (without its selector), and with a `checked` state. then, on click, `postDelayed` set the state of your view to checked (you need to implement `Checkable`).


something less hacky to try -
since `RippleDrawable` is just a `LayerDrawable`, try overriding `onStateChange` to detect pressed state, and then change the "content" layer's background to something else (manually), so that when the animation is done, you see the selected color.

Answer (score 1):

This has preserved the ripple animation for me on selection.

With your ripple drawable use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_selected="true"
                  android:drawable="@color/selected_color" />
            <item android:drawable="@color/normal_color" />
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

On your adapter, call `setHasStableIds(true)` and implement `getItemId` to return unique values representing your rows.

When an item is selected, do:

```
ViewHolder oldViewHolder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(oldItemId);
oldViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(false);

ViewHolder newViewHolder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(newItemId);
newViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(true);
```

Also in your Adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    ...

    viewHolder.itemView.setSelected(isSelected);

    ...
}
```

On a side note, the focused selector is used for highlighting navigation on devices that use a d-pad like TV and some older phones.

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this a lot.
I ended up doing it with a `<layer-list/>`

You can see my solution in an answer to a question very similar to yours here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31335539/844206