# Why does a list and state list selector ripple animation not draw completely on API24?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rippledrawable, statelistdrawable

In this case the question is pertaining to a RecyclerView, where I'd like the ripple effect to animate (roughly if not exactly) from where the finger touched with a custom colour to the full extent of a view, much like a listview row in terms of the view's layout, and finally end its animation with the row selected in another colour.

I have

**items_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rowLayout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingBottom="5dp"
  android:paddingTop="5dp"
  android:background="@drawable/items_ripple_state_selector"
  >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_unit"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/item_amount"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="unit" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_amount"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="amount" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4.6"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="title"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/item_description"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/item_title"
      android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/item_title"
      android:text="description" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and

**items_ripple_state_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <selector>
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/state_activated" />
      <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/state_selected" />
      <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    </selector>
  </item>
  <item>
    <ripple android:color="@color/primary">
      <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
      </item>
    </ripple>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Tests that came out bad**

I have done tests on the following devices, in which the ripple effect animation stops way too early, resulting more in a "blip"/"ping" rather than a full expansion to the view's edges.

- Nexus 6, Nougat (7.0.0), API 24
- Nexus 5X, Nougat (7.x.x), not 100% on minor version
- Different AVD's targetting API level 24

**Tests that came out good**

I have done tests on the following devices, in which the ripple effect animation  animates *beautifully* in what I would expect is its full length, to the view's edges:

- Nexus 5, Marshmallow (6.0.1), API level 23
- Nexus 4, Lollipop (5.1.1), API level 22

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on with this. It looks pretty horrible on the N6 and N5X as the animation stops mid-way, with no distinct pattern as to when the animation stops.

I've read quite a few SO questions as well as RecyclerView, StateListDrawable and RippleDrawable documentation, but there's just nothing that gives any explanation to the behaviour I see.

The closest I have come, which is what I'm currently using, and what I've shared in this post in terms of code, came from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31335539/975641

Does anyone have an idea as to why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know the explicit answer, but I know this is very common occurrence if the RecyclerView is binding way too much. This is caused from either calling `notifyItem_____` or `notifyDatasetChanged` too much on the adapter.

Comment: Alright, I could look into this and see what that yields. What makes this issue harder to pinpoint the source of the problem is that the same code works find on just a couple API level notches down.

Comment: It may be more of a symptom of a bigger problem. I suspect that what's happening though is the RecyclerView is binding items again on the same items.  It would look like the items didn't change, but all the animations would reset.

Comment: Yes, you put the nail on the head on this one! I commented out the notifyChange call in the ContentProvider, which feeds the RecyclerView its cursor, and the ripple effect is now animating as I expect it to. If you'd like to put up your comment or something similar to it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Tricky debugging, this one!

Comment: Well, it'll be harder fixing it because you do still want those notifications if the dataset is updated.  Otherwise your RecyclerView will be out of date (or you'll get an exception sometimes).

Comment: Yeah, I need to reconsider the way I notify the changes, in this case when checking/setting an item state on pressing it. Currently, the touch event passes the change in state to the ContentProvider, which then returns with a new cursor. I'm considering not notifying the adapter of the change, and having the viewholder keep the state within itself, to avoid getting the cursor to get unnecessary updates. I'll also look into what notifyItem____ could yield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the specific reason for why it works in Marshmallow, but not Nougat. However, most commonly when you see this issue, it's because the `RecyclerView` is refreshing and/or re-binding way too much.

Basically what would happen is

1. User clicks
2. Animation starts
3. Something called for a rebinding on that item
4. RecyclerView calls rebind on the item
5. Animation is canceled because the view resets.

Most commonly this occurs when calling either `RecyclerAdapter#notifyItemChanged(int)` method or `RecyclerAdapter#notifyDatasetChanged()` too many times.

It would be best to use the `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItem____` methods if possible. `notifyDatasetChanged()` will cause a rebind on all the items in the list. Using the `notifyItem_____` methods will make sure that only individual items are updated when they need to be.  Otherwise, you need to ensure to only call `nofityDatasetChanged()` when there are actual changed in the dataset.

Another common issue would be if the app is calling `invalidate` in either the `RecyclerView` or any parent of the `RecyclerView`.  This would cause a refresh of the entire View tree which would require a rebind for all the items in a `RecyclerView`.